# Connect Power Bi gateway to my Network drive doesn't work

Tags: powerbi, gateway, network-drive

This monday I installed my Power Bi gateway which is connected to my local drive (C:/). I uploaded my online PowerBi analysis on microsoft sharepoint. Everything works perfectly.

My next step is to install the gateway for my network drive because that way my PC doesn't have to run once the autorefresh is supposed to refresh. I have a problem, I can't get the gateway on my network drive. Someone else already asked this question on stack overflow but there where no answers, that's why I want to ask it again.

I can change the path of my Power Bi analysis to my network drive and I can also upload the files to app.powerbi.com, that's not the problem.

If you have questions don't bother asking.

I hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: Where is the gateway installed? Can it see the network drive, have you set up the folder location in the service?

Comment: Gateway is installed on the C:// drive of my own PC. Could this be the reason? I thought if I used my personal login on the gateway it could use my security clearance to go to the network drive as well to link with the datasource. I might be wrong so I am going to check this. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

I had 2x reports using Gateway where 1x would not connect to my work's network. The other report ok. I re-confirmed credentials and access rights and all were ok. Therefore, it was a problem with the 1x report somehow. I then gradually stripped my report down and eventually found the problem. It also used a SharePoint Excel file to obtain some data, it was having this SharePoint file along with a network data source that caused the problem. As soon as I removed the SharePoint link, everything worked ok! This is annoying because the spreadsheet was far more accessible via SharePoint. The best debug you can do is to 1) check you data source settings and ensure you're logged on to all of them, 2) strip your report back until it works, 3) create a super-basic report by grabbing one data source from your network and using a basic table to display contents.